# Spark and non-denormalized tables

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I know Spark works much better with denormalized tables, where all the needed data is in one line. I wondering, if it is not the case, it would have a way to retrieve data from previous, or next, rows.

Example:

Formula:
value = (value from 2 year ago) + (current year value) / (value from 2 year ahead)

```
Table
+-------+-----+
|   YEAR|VALUE|
+-------+-----+
|   2015| 100 |
|   2016| 34  |
|   2017| 32  |
|   2018| 22  |
|   2019| 14  |
|   2020| 42  |
|   2021| 88  |
+-------+-----+

Dataset<Row> dataset ...
Dataset<Results> results = dataset.map(row -> {
   int currentValue = Integer.valueOf(row.getAs("VALUE")); // 2019   
   // non sense code just to exemplify    
   int twoYearsBackValue = Integer.valueOf(row[???].getAs("VALUE")); // 2016
   int twoYearsAheadValue = Integer.valueOf(row[???].getAs("VALUE")); // 2021
   double resultValue = twoYearsBackValue + currentValue / twoYearsAheadValue;
   return new Result(2019, resultValue);
});
Results[] results = results.collect();
```

Is it possible to grab these values (that belongs to other rows) without changing the table format (no denormalization, no pivots ...) and also without collecting the data, or does it go totally against Spark/BigData principles?

Comment: What are you asking? What happened when you tried it? How are you executing it? If you're following Spark/BigData principles then you should realize that the nodes are going to **lazily** read unconnected blocks in parallel. If you aren't collecting the data; what do you intend to do with these results?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I've edited my question to try to exemplify what I'm try to accomplish. I know map, neither row[???], are non sense code, but maybe it helps me to explain my question. When I said without collection the data, I meant at time to calculate only.

Comment: Window functions...